# Jekyll select current page url and change its class

Tags: html, jekyll

I've been using Jekyll for a static site (so that its easy to maintain), and have been stuck at the following feature :

This is my link bar :

```
<ul id="links">
    <li class="first"><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="./associate.html">Associate With Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="./media.html">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="./clients.html">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a  href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `active` class handles the coloring. What I want is this class be applied by jekyll depending on some variable set using liquid/YAML.

Is there some easy way to go about this?

Since the bar is common to all the pages, it is now in the default layout. I could go around by using Javascript to detect the url, and do the highlighting but was wondering if there was any way of doing this in Jekyll.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I do this in two pages I have set up in Jekyll.

The first thing I do is creating an entry inside _config.yml with the information of all the pages:

```
# this goes inside _config.yml. Change as required
navigation:
- text: What we do
  url: /en/what-we-do/
- text: Who we are
  url: /en/who-we-are/
- text: Projects
  url: /en/projects/
  layout: project
- text: Blog
  url: /en/blog/
  layout: post
```

Then, on my main layout, I use that information to generate the navigation links. On each link, I compare the url of the link with the url of the current page. If they are equal, the page is active. Otherwise, they are not.

There's a couple special cases: all blog posts must highlight the "blog" link, and the front pages (English and Spanish) must not present the nav bar. For both cases, I rely on the fact that blog posts and front pages have specific layouts (notice that the "Blog" and "Project" links on the yaml have an extra parameter called "layout")

The navigation code is generated like this:

```
{% unless page.layout == 'front' %}
  <ul class="navigation">
    {% for link in site.navigation %}
      {% assign current = nil %}
      {% if page.url == link.url or page.layout == link.layout %}
        {% assign current = 'current' %}
      {% endif %}

      <li class="{% if forloop.first %}first{% endif %} {{ current }} {% if forloop.last %}last{% endif %}">
        <a class="{{ current }}" href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endunless %}
```

I still have to remember adding an entry to _config.yaml every time I add a new page, and then restart Jekyll, but it happens very infrequently now.

I *think* the navigation yaml could go inside an _include called "navigation" or something similar, but I haven't tried using yaml inside those so I don't know whether it will work. In my case, since I've got a multi-lingual site, it's easier to have everything inside config (missing translations are easier to spot)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly but with one caveat. I can't get it to match the root url (/) since the browser automatically removes that. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. You mean the browser removing code from your html?

Comment: In any case, if you need to add a link to the root in your nav, you can use the "layout trick", just like I did for the blog posts. Make a "root" or "front" layout and assign it to the page and to the link.

Comment: Check this : http://www.roorkites.com. I cannot get the Home url to be parsed with the above solution (in the linkbar). I might resort to the layout trick but I was looking for a simpler solution. The repo is at [github](https://github.com/approx/approx.github.com)

Comment: @Capt.Nemo. Pull request sent. The issue was that the permalink of index.html, is, by default "index.html". I've forced it to be "/" instead by adding `permalink: /` to its top yaml section.

Answer (score 54):

As a further extension on the work of the other, here is a way to make it work without soggy `index.html` showing on all your beautiful URLs:

```
---
navigation:
 - text: Home
   url: /
 - text: Blah
   url: /blah/
---
{% assign url = page.url|remove:'index.html' %}
{% for link in page.navigation %}
<li {% if url == link.url %}class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{link.url}}" title="{{link.title}}">{{link.text}}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The gold is in the `assign` statement which gets the page URL (which naturally includes the index.html and then strips it off to match the page.navigation pretty URLs.

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't got any upvotes, it's by far the cleanest and easiest way to do this. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: :( This didn't work... I spent quite some time to figure it out: `{% capture url %}{{ page.url | remove:'index.html' }}{% endcapture %}`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. The ` {% assign url = page.url|remove:'index.html' %} ` was what I was missing! Thanks.

Comment: While this works, note that in version 3 of Jekyll, you'll need to access the navigation values via `layout.navigation`. See https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4246

Comment: Also, you'll need to change `|remove:'index.html' %}` to `|remove:'.html' %}` to remove the trailing `.html`.

Comment: Anyone else having issues with this not working on index.html (it works on every other page..)

Answer (score 18):

This may be a new feature since the question first appeared, but I've discovered this can all be done in one file:

1. define the navigation as a variable in the yaml header
2. loop over the variable using liquid

So in my `_layouts/base.html` I have:

```
---
navigation:
- text: Home
  url: /index.html
- text: Travel
  title: Letters home from abroad
  url: /travel.html
---

<ul>
    {% for link in page.navigation %}
    <li {% if page.url == link.url %}class="current"{% endif %}>
       <a href="{{link.url}}" title="{{link.title}}">{{link.text}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

Which generates this on the `Home` page:

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="/index.html" title="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/travel.html" title="Letters home from abroad">Travel</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this on the `Travel` page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/index.html" title="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="/travel.html" title="Letters home from abroad">Travel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this works, note that in version 3 of Jekyll, you'll need to access the navigation values via `layout.navigation`. See https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4246

Comment: Also, you'll need to change `|remove:'index.html' %}` to `|remove:'.html' %}` to remove the trailing `.html`.

Answer (score 12):

I needed something simple, this is what I did.

In my front matter I added a variable called `active`

e.g.

```
---
layout: generic
title:  About
active: about
---
```

I have a navigation include with the following section

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% if page.active == "home" %}
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if page.active == "blog" %}
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="../blog/">Blog</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if page.active == "about" %}
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="../about">About</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

This works for me as the amount of links in the navigation are very narrow.

Comment: Easy to implement and exactly suits my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

#### Same navigation on all pages

After reading all that answers, I came up with a new and easier to maintain solution:

1. Add `{% include nav.html %}` to your `_layouts/layout.html` file
2. Add a `nav.html` file to your `_includes` folder
3. Add the following content to your `nav.html` file. It will determine if your link is on the current page and add a class of `active` as well as remove `index.html` from your link. It will also work with a subfolder like `/repo-name`, which is needed for **GitHub `gh-pages` Pages branch**.

   ```
   <nav>
       <ul class="nav">
           {% assign url = page.url|remove:'index.html' %}
           {% for link in site.navigation %}
               {% assign state = '' %}
               {% if page.url == link.url %}
                   {% assign state = 'active ' %}
               {% endif %}
               <li class="{{ state }}nav-item">
                   <a href="{% if page.url == link.url %}{{ site.baseurl }}{% else %}{{ site.baseurl }}{{ link.url }}{% endif %}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
               </li>
           {% endfor %}
       </ul>
   </nav>
   ```
4. Then add the nav link array to your `_config.yml` file as following. Mind the right indentation, as YAML is pretty picky on that (Jekyll as well).

   ```
   navigation:
         - text: Home
           title: Back to home page
           url: /index.html
         - text: Intro
           title: An introduction to the project
           url: /intro.html 
         - text: etc.
           title: ...
           url: /foo.html
   ```

#### Navigation only on home - "back" for others

Assuming that the link to your "Home"-page (`index.html`) is the first array part inside the `_config.html`s `navigation` array, you can use the following snippet to show the navigation to the different pages on the main/home page and a link back to the home page on all other pages:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="grid">
        {% assign url = page.url | remove:'/index.html' %}
        {% assign home = site.navigation.first %}
        {% if url == empty %}
            {% for link in site.navigation %}
                {% assign state = '' %}
                {% if page.url == link.url %}
                    {% assign state = 'active ' %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if home.url != link.url %}
                    <li class="{{ state }}nav-item">
                        <a href="{% if page.url == link.url %}{{ site.baseurl }}{% else %}{{ site.baseurl }}{{ link.url }}{% endif %}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="{{ home.url }}" title="{{ home.title }}">{{ home.text }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (sorry for non-english code):

```
<nav>
  <a href="/kursevi" {% if page.url == '/kursevi/' %} class="active"{% endif %}>Kursevi</a>
  <a href="/radovi" {% if page.url == '/radovi/' %} class="active"{% endif %}>Radovi</a>
  <a href="/blog" {% if page.url == '/blog/' %} class="active"{% endif %}>Blog</a>
  <a href="/kontakt" {% if page.url == '/kontakt/' %} class="active"{% endif %}>Kontakt</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. I read through the first couple of highly-rated answers, and ended up implementing almost exactly this. Came back to post my answer, and found this one near the bottom. Should have more upvotes, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Navigation highlighting logic is the last thing I would do in server side. I'd rather stick with nice, clean and unobtrusive approach using JS/jQuery (if this option works for you).

1. The elements which need to be highlighted go inside a common layout like this:

   ```
   <nav>
     <a id="section1" href="#">Section 1</a>
     <a id="section2" href="#">Section 2</a>
     <a id="section3" href="#">Section 3</a>
   </nav>
   ```
2. In your page (or even in nested layouts) you place an element with `data-ref="#section1"` (in fact, any jQuery selector will work).
3. Now, include following JS snippet (shown as jQuery, but any framework will do) in `<head>`:

   ```
   $(function() {
     $("[data-ref]").each(function() {
       $($(this).attr("data-ref")).addClass("current");
     });
   });
   ```

This approach is nice, because it makes no assumptions on underlying architecture, frameworks, languages and template engines.

**Update:** As [some folks pointed out](http://thanpol.as/javascript/you-dont-need-dom-ready/) you might want to omit the `$(function() { ... })` part which binds the script to DOM ready event — and just push the script down to the bottom of your `<body>`.

Comment: Sure you can fix everything by _just using jQuery_ but it's **far** from nice, clean and unobtrusive. By your reasoning, the whole website should be built in jQuery since it _makes no assumptions on underlying tech_

Comment: @bfred.it Yup, this one is very constructive. By my reasoning, navigation highlighting *is just* navigation highlighting. And everything else *is* everything else.

Comment: Literally everything else on this page is far nicer. I picked Oli's version for my project.

Comment: Revisited my own answer after a while. I am still pretty convinced about this one. Here are a few points, if you don't mind. 1. Extensive pattern-matching with `if-then-else` (this is what every other answers suggest) is always considered a code smell, especially in templates where literally any logic is an unwanted visitor, because clean document semantics code is mixed with logical branches into one big spaghetti ball.

Comment: 2. Pattern-matching also scales terribly. Suppose you have two navigation bars (main nav and subnav) and you want to highlight both the section (in the main nav) and the page (in the subnav). With `if-then-else` approach you are forced to repeat those yarn balls for every highlighting context (or maybe even copy-paste them!), while my proposed approach only requires an `id` on the navigation link and another `data-ref` attribute inside the rendered document which will point to it.

Comment: 3. One could argue that having the class attribute written in the response is more SEO-friendly then setting it at the client, but none of the SEO guides and references out there can prove such a statement. The `active` class also makes negligible difference to the overall document semantics (the `active` class is neither a specification, nor a convention: some may call it `current`, some may call it `this`). The only problem with my approach is jQuery, which can be easily rewritten using `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: No, seriously, I can't see any **strong** arguments against client-side navigation highlighting (of course as long as you are not designing a noscript page :). I'll be glad if someone could point them out for me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the solution of incarnate, the simplest possible line of code with jQuery is this:

```
    $( "a[href='{{ page.url | remove: "index.html" }}']" ).addClass("current");
```

Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you sir! (former Incarnate speaking, hehe)

Answer (score 2):

I took a simple CSS approach. First, add an identifier in the front matter...

```
---
layout: page
title: Join us
permalink: /join-us/
nav-class: join <-----
---
```

Add this as a class in `<body>` **and** your nav...

```
<body class="{{ page.nav-class }}">
```

and

```
<li class="{{ page.nav-class }}">...</a></li>
```

Then link these for all pages in CSS, e.g:

```
.about .about a,
.join .join a,
.contact .contact a {
color: #fff;
}
```

The main downside being you need to hard code the style rules.

Answer (score 2):

With Jekyll 3.4.3, this works :

```
<ul>
    {% for my_page in site.pages %} 
        {% if my_page.title %}
            <li {% if my_page.url == page.url %} class="active" {% endif %}>
                <a href="{{ my_page.url | relative_url }}">{{ my_page.title | escape }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: This should have more upvotes. I simply did `if page.url == whatever.url` inside my `for` loop. Thing of beauty!