# Jekyll - Automatically highlight current tab in menu bar

Tags: jekyll

I am using github to host a static site and Jekyll to generate it.

I have a menu bar (as `<ul>`) and would like the `<li>` corresponding to the current page to be assigned a different class for CSS highlighting.

So something like pseudo code:

`<li class={(hrefpage==currentpage)?"highlight":"nothighlight"} ...>`

Or perhaps even generate the whole `<ul>` in Jekyll.

How can this be done with minimal changes outside of the offending `<ul>`?

Comment: To chose which pages to use, copy paste from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17215331/895245

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Yes you can do this.**
To accomplish this we will take advantage of the fact that the current page is always represented by the liquid variable: `page` in the template, and also that each post/page has a unique identifier in its `page.url` attribute.

This means that we just have to use a loop to build our navigation page, and by doing so we can check `page.url` against every member of the loop. If it finds a match, it knows to highlight that element. Here we go:

```
  {% for node in site.pages %}
    {% if page.url == node.url %}
      <li class="active"><a href="{{node.url}}" class="active">{{node.title}}</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

This works as expected. However you probably don't want all your page's in your nav bar. In order to emulate page "grouping" you can something like this:

```
## Put the following code in a file in the _includes folder at: ./_includes/pages_list

{% for node in pages_list %}
  {% if group == null or group == node.group %}
    {% if page.url == node.url %}
      <li class="active"><a href="{{node.url}}" class="active">{{node.title}}</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign pages_list = nil %}
{% assign group = nil %}
```

Now pages can be "grouped". To give a page a group you need to specify it in the pages YAML Front Matter:

```
---
title: blah
categories: blah
group: "navigation"
---
```

Finally you can use your new code!
Wherever you need your navigation to go in your template, simply "call" your include file and pass it some pages and the group you want to display:

```
<ul>
  {% assign pages_list = site.pages %}
  {% assign group = 'navigation' %}
  {% include pages_list %}
</ul>
```

#### Examples

This functionality is part of the [Jekyll-Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com) framework.
You can see exact documentation for the code outlined here: http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/bootstrap-api.html#jbpages_list

Finally you can see it in action within the website itself. Just look at the righthand navigation and you will see the current page is highlighted in green: [Example highlighted nav link](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/bootstrap-api.html)

Comment: Great question, great answer, thanks.  It was straight forward to modify this for a manually selected list of tabs too.  took a moment to realize that page.url includes the '/', eg. "/index.html", not "index.html"

Comment: This approach results in a Jekyll error for me. `jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  The included file '/Users/joelglovier/project/jekyllsite/_includes/pages_list' should exist and should not be a symlink`

Comment: Way too complex for something that should be built-in to Jekyll.

Comment: @cameronjroe try adding the `.html` extension to pages_list and including that instead

Answer (score 50):

I feel like for the simplest navigation requirement, the listed solutions are overly complex. Here's a solution that involves no front matter, javascript, loops, etc.

Since we have access to the page URL, we can normalize and split the URL and test against the segments, like so:

```
{% assign current = page.url | downcase | split: '/' %}

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='/about' {% if current[1] == 'about' %}class='current'{% endif %}>about</a></li>
    <li><a href='/blog' {% if current[1] == 'blog' %}class='current'{% endif %}>blog</a></li>
    <li><a href='/contact' {% if current[1] == 'contact' %}class='current'{% endif %}>contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Of course, this is only useful if static segments provide the means to delineate the navigation. Anything more complicated, and you'll have to use front matter like @RobertKenny demonstrated.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but shouldn't it be `classs="active"`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功 if your CSS has the style `.active` , then yes. In the answer above, the author is saying that the class to call in her/his stylesheet is `.current`. No big deal.

Comment: @BrianZ it's official: too much Bootstrap melts your brain :)

Comment: for homepage i had to set {% if current[1] == null %}

Answer (score 18):

Here's my solution which I think is the best way to highlight the current page:

Define a *navigation list* on your **_config.yml** like this:

```
navigation:
  - title: blog
    url: /blog/
  - title: about
    url: /about/
  - title: projects
    url: /projects/
```

Then in your **_includes/header.html** file you must loop through the list to check if the current page (*page.url*) resembles any item of the navigation list, if so then you just set the active class and add it to the `<a>` tag:

```
<nav>
  {% for item in site.navigation %}
      {% assign class = nil %}
      {% if page.url contains item.url %}
          {% assign class = 'active' %}
      {% endif %}
      <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="{{ class }}">
          {{ item.title }}
      </a>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

And because you're using the *contains* operator instead of the equals *=* operator, you don't have to write extra code to make it work with URLs such as *'/blog/post-name/'* or *'projects/project-name/'*. So it works really well.

P.S: Don't forget to set the *permalink* variable on your pages.

Comment: This is my favourite solution as it means I can choose the order of the pages.

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesn't work if you have a nav link with url `/` because all page urls contain the leading slash.  The following works:  ```{% for link in site.navigation %}
        {% assign class = nil %}
        {% if page.url == link.url %}
          {% assign class = 'active' %}
        {% elsif page.url != '/' and page.url contains link.url %}
          {% assign class = 'active parent' %}
        {% endif %}
        <a href="{{link.url}}" class="{{class}}">{{link.title}}</a>
      {% endfor %}```

Answer (score 17):

Similar to @ben-foster's solution but without using any jQuery

I needed something simple, this is what I did.

In my front matter I added a variable called `active`

e.g.

```
---
layout: generic
title:  About
active: about
---
```

I have a navigation include with the following section

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% if page.active == "home" %}
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if page.active == "blog" %}
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="../blog/">Blog</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if page.active == "about" %}
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="../about">About</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

This works for me as the amount of links in the navigation are very narrow.

Comment: Thanks @SurenderLohia I like to keep things as single as I can.

Answer (score 6):

I used a little bit of JavaScript to accomplish this. I have the following structure in the menu:

```
<ul id="navlist">
  <li><a id="index" href="index.html">Index</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
```

This javascript snippet highlights the current corresponding page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    $("#navlist a").each(function(index) {
        if (pathname.toUpperCase().indexOf($(this).text().toUpperCase()) != -1)
            $(this).addClass("current");
    });

    if ($("a.current").length == 0)
        $("a#index").addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: I personally think this is cleaner than the above method. The method above starts to get ugly if you want to order the pages in your nav or if you wanted to have "Index" highlighted by default.

Comment: This is simple and easy to get started with adding class to current page element. The "accepted" answer took about hour to figure out how and why. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

My approach is to define a custom variable in the YAML front matter of the page and output this on the `<body>` element:

```
<body{% if page.id %} data-current-page="{{ page.id }}"{% endif %}>
```

My navigation links include the identifier of the page that they link to:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="artists.html" data-page-id="artists">artists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-page-id="contact">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-page-id="about">about</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In the page front matter we set the page id:

```
---
layout: default
title: Our artists
id: artists
---
```

And finally a bit of jQuery to set the active link:

```
// highlight current page
var currentPage = $("body").data("current-page");
if (currentPage) {
    $("a[data-page-id='" + currentPage + "']").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: I thought that this method was very easy to follow and allows for easy sorting of menu items. I am very new to Jekyll so the other methods intimidated me a bit, but I am very comfortable with jQuery. May not be 100% perfect for the purist, but it works and works well.

Comment: If you want a liquid only solution, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46984009/2397550

Answer (score 2):

The navigation of your website should be an unordered list. To get the list items to lighten up when they are active, the following liquid script adds an 'active' class to them. This class should be styled with CSS. To detect which link is active, the script uses ‘contains’, as you can see in the code below.

```
<ul>
  <li {% if page.url contains '/getting-started' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="/getting-started/">Getting started</a>
  </li>
  ...
  ...
  ...
</ul>
```

This code is compatible with all permalink styles in Jekyll. The ‘contains’ statement succesfully highlights the first menu item at the following URL’s:

- getting-started/
- getting-started.html
- getting-started/index.html
- getting-started/subpage/
- getting-started/subpage.html

Source: http://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/simple-menu/

Answer (score 2):

Lot's of confusing answers here.
I simply use an `if`:

```
{% if page.name == 'limbo-anim.md' %}active{% endif %}
```

I refer directly to the page and putting it inside the class I want to

```
<li><a class="pr-1 {% if page.name == 'limbo-anim.md' %}activo{% endif %} " href="limbo-anim.html">Animación</a></li>
```

Done. Quick.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where you put each of those elements? header.html, or?

Answer (score 1):

Lot of good answers are already there.

Try this.

I slightly alter the above answers.

`_data/navigation.yaml`

```
- name: Home
  url: /
  active: home
- name: Portfolio
  url: /portfolio/
  active: portfolio
- name: Blog
  url: /blog/
  active: blog
```

In a page -> `portfolio.html` (Same for all pages with a relative active page name)

```
---
layout: default
title: Portfolio
permalink: /portfolio/
active: portfolio
---

<div>
  <h2>Portfolio</h2>
</div>
```

`Navigation html part`

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  {% for item in site.data.navigation %}
    <li class="main-menu-item">
      {% if {{page.active}} == {{item.active}} %}
        <a class="main-menu-link active" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <a class="main-menu-link" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `page.path` and going off the filename.

```
<a href="/" class="{% if page.path == 'index.html' %}active{% endif %}">home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for reviving an almost 12 year old question, but I think it's worth mentioning [`aria-current="page"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-current). This is a very useful attribute to screenreader users.

Here's an example of how to implement it in Jekyll:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/home"{% if page.url == '/home' %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}>Home</a>
  <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/about"{% if page.url == '/about' %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}>About</a>
</ul>
```

Read more about it here: https://benmyers.dev/blog/semantic-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the Minima theme for jekyll, you only need to add a ternary on the class attribute in header.html:

```
 <a {% if my_page.url == page.url %} class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ my_page.url | relative_url }}">
```

the full excerpt:

```
        <div class="trigger">
        {%- for path in page_paths -%}
          {%- assign my_page = site.pages | where: "path", path | first -%}
          {%- if my_page.title -%}
          <a {% if my_page.url == page.url %} class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ my_page.url | relative_url }}">{{ my_page.title | escape }}</a>
          {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
      </div>
```

add this to your _config.yml

```
header_pages:
  - classes.markdown
  - activities.markdown
  - teachers.markdown
```

And then of course your css:

```
   a.active {
                color: #e6402a;
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a jQuery method to do the same

```
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;

  $(".menu.right a").each(function(index) {
    if (pathname === $(this).attr('href') ) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
  });
```