# Octopress site.navigation

Tags: web, blogs, jekyll, octopress

I have this thing in my Octopress blog:

```
<ul class="nav">
    {% for link in site.navigation %}
        <li {% if page.url == link.url %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What this:

```
{% for link in site.navigation %}
```

I checked `_config.yml`, but didn't find `navigation` definition. I searched the whole project for the string "navigation", without avail. Can someone please help me understand what this `{% for link in site.navigation %}` is, and how I can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, [kikito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369044/456434) *thinks* he's correct. Well, yes. Spot on, my friend.

> I think the navigation yaml could go inside an _include called "navigation" or something similar, but I haven't tried using yaml inside those so I don't know whether it will work. In my case, since I've got a multi-lingual site, it's easier to have everything inside config (missing translations are easier to spot)

Bascially, go to `navigation.html` inside the `_includes` directory, and you may find the source where `site.navigation` is populated from. In my case:

```
{% include custom/navigation.html %}
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    {% if site.github_user %}
    <li><a href="http://github.com/{{ site.github_user }}" title="Github Profile"><i class="icon-github-sign social-navbar"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if site.bitbucket_user %}
    <li><a href="http://bitbucket.org/{{ site.bitbucket_user }}" title="BitBucket Profile"><i class="icon-bitbucket-sign social-navbar"></i></a></li>
    {% endif %}
    ...
</ul>
```