# Add a page title to body class with Jekyll

Tags: css, jekyll

Im trying to repose these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366188/jekyll-select-current-page-url-and-change-its-class) to give each of my pages a body class of the page url with Jekyll? Using this code is getting there, but its adding an unwanted '*/*' and trailing '*.html*', eg: */page-title.html*

```
{% assign url = page.url|remove:'index.html' %}
  {% for link in page.navigation %}
    <body {% if url == link.url %}class="{{ page.url }}"{% endif %}>
{% endfor %}
```

**Desired output**

```
<body class="page-title">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest manner, but you could do this:

```
class="{{ page.url | split: "/" | last | remove: ".html" }}"
```

If your title variables in your pages front matter are the same as your CSS classes, you could also do:

```
class="{{ page.title }}"
```